# Accessing argument from anonymous function on another function

Tags: julia

I have to code a function with the signature `contains(name)`. This function will only be called on a given context, which is

```
(allNames)->contains("myname")
```

I have coded:

```
function contains(name)
    for n in allNames
        if n === name
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

The problem is that I can't access `allNames` inside function `contains`. Meanwhile, I can't just pass it as argument to the `contains` function, as I can't modify the signature.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - are you just trying to implement the `in` function as an exercise? (It seems what you're trying to do is `in("myname", allNames)` where `allNames` is a collection of names)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you either want

1. [Dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping), which is only achievable with hacks and generally frowned upon in language design, or
2. a [partially applied function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), which you can write by returning a closure:

   ```
   containedin(allNames) = name -> in(allNames, name)
   ```

   or, in this specific case, just as

   ```
   in(allNames)
   ```

   which will return a `Base.Fix1`.